# Valid widths for the Settings Pane in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, appsettings

I have a condition wherein the Header Text of the Settings Command in the PopUp is Larger and as per the Specification the width of 346px is a bit short for the complete text and the Width of 646px seems a bit much larger for the PopUp Header. I would like to know whether is it ok if we use custom widths for the Settings Popup which will solve my problem and if this is not an alternative i would be pleased if an alternative workaround is suggested.

Thanks for your Suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really stick to the recommended widths of 346px or 646px.  If your header doesn't fit, why not change the font size, or add line breaks?